# PHAsset is returning a nil value for the UIImage when using PHImageManager

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

Any idea why this would return nil for 'thisImage' after adding in the requestImageOption settings?  If options is set to nil thisAsset returns a value but it's a low res image, definitely not original high res.  I'm trying to return the original image from the PHAsset (thisAsset)

```
    if let thisAsset:PHAsset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset {
          arrImageIdentifiers.append(thisAsset.localIdentifier)

        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let requestImageOption = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestImageOption.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.highQualityFormat

        manager.requestImage(for: thisAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.default, options: requestImageOption, resultHandler: {(thisImage, _) in

            Object.tempImage = thisImage

            print("Picture metadata: \(thisAsset)")
            let creationDate = thisAsset.creationDate

            PhotoMeta.createDate = creationDate

            })
            //Get a reference to the camera view controller and call the savePhoto method
            let cameraVC = self.selectedViewController as? CameraViewController

            if let cameraVC = cameraVC {
                cameraVC.savePhoto(image: Object.tempImage!)
            }
    }
```

Comment: Try with `requestImageOption.isSynchronous = true ` once as well

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal can you make this an answer.  That worked, thanks

Comment: It may seem to work but it’s wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set requestOptions's `isSynchronus` to `true` to resolve your problem:

```
    let requestImageOption = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestImageOption.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.highQualityFormat
    requestImageOption.isSynchronous = true

    manager.requestImage(for: thisAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.default, options: requestImageOption, resultHandler: {(thisImage, _) in

        //....
    }
```

Comment: That’s wrong. You must not set this to synchronous on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me, was to set `options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true` in `requestImageOption (aka PHImageRequestOptions())`.